# How can I calculate the size in byte of my account?

Tags: web3.js

I'm using `@solana/web3.js` to work with solana. How can I calculate the size in byte of my accounts??
I need the correct size to call `getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption`

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the size in bytes of your accounts in Solana using @solana/web3.js, you can use the Buffer.from method to convert your data into a buffer and then use the length property of the buffer. Here's an example of how to calculate the size of your data:

```
const data = Buffer.from('your_data_here', 'utf8'); // Convert your data to a buffer
const sizeInBytes = data.length; // Calculate the size in bytes
console.log(sizeInBytes);
```

and from the above, you can now calculate the size in getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption. like,

```
const minimumBalance = await connection.getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption(sizeInBytes);
console.log(minimumBalance);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Rust source, and you are using Rust Analyzer or a similar formatting tool, you can hover over the struct name to see the size and alignment, it'll show something like: `// size = 1360 (0x550), align = 0x8`

On the Rust side you can also do:

```
impl YourStruct {
    pub const LEN: usize = std::mem::size_of::<YourStruct>();
}
```

and when you init the struct:

```
    #[account(
        init,
        seeds = [
          some_seed.key().as_ref(),
          b"whatever",
        ],
        bump,
        payer = admin,
        space = 8 + YourStruct::LEN,
    )]
```

When using this value in TS, we usually just hardcode the size + 8 value we get from Rust. Also note you are free to allocate a *larger* space, and rent is very cheap, so if you know your account is ~5000 you can just allocate ~6000 and be done with it.